# SASS / SCSS: Interpolate variable from string / name

Tags: variables, sass, concatenation, string-interpolation

Is it possible to get a variable by name?

I tried building the following function, but it's not working as expected...

```css
@function variable-lookup($variable, $suffix: "") {
  $value: null;
  @if ($suffix != "" and global-variable-exists($variable+"-"+$suffix)) {
    $value: #{$variable+"-"+$suffix};
  }
  @else if (global-variable-exists($variable)) {
    $value: #{$variable};
  }
  @return $value;
}
```

Here's an example of how it might be used:

```css
$primary: #000;
$primary-hover: blue;

a {
  color: variable-lookup("primary", "base");

  &:hover {
    color: variable-lookup("primary", "hover");
  }
}
```

The real power would come in when I want to write a bunch of context-specific, shorthand wrapper functions around this "variable-lookup" function.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to interpolate `#{$variable+"-"+$suffix}` to give the value `primary-base` and further trying to get the value of same variable name is **not possible**. `primary-base` is already a value and and can't be interpreted as a variable name. That sort of thing could lead to a lot of chaos.

For what you want to accomplish, you are better of using a `map` and checking for the `key` in that map

```
$colours: (
  'primary': red,
  'primary-base': blue
);

@function variable_lookup($colour, $suffix: '') {
  $value: null;
  @if ( $suffix != '' and map-has-key($colours, unquote($colour+'-'+$suffix)) ) {
    $value: map-get($colours, unquote($colour+'-'+$suffix));
  } @else if ( map-has-key($colours, unquote($colour)) ) {
    $value: map-get($colours, unquote($colour));
  }
  @return $value;
}

div {
  color: variable-lookup(primary, base);
}

p {
  color: variable-lookup(primary);
}
```

This compiles to the following css

```
div {
  color: blue; }

p {
  color: red; }
```

Your code stored colours as variables but I used those names as `keys` in `maps`

This allowed to simulate the checking of variables in your code using the `map-has-key` method. If that returns true, the `key` exists and we can get the value which in this case would be the colour using `map-get`

**UPDATED ANSWER**
One way to address the issues you raised in your comments would be to define the variables and use them in as values in the map

```
$primary: #fff;
$warning: yellow; 

$colours: ( primary: $primary, 
            primary-hover: darken($primary, 5%), 
            secondary: $warning, 
            secondary-hover: darken($warning, 5%) );
```

Another way would be to iterate through two lists and map colour to a style

```
$colours: ();

$list: primary success warning; //map primary to blue, success to green and so on
$shades: blue green yellow;

@for $i from 1 through length($list) {
  $key: nth($list, $i);
  $value: nth($shades, $i);
  $colours: map-merge($colours, ($key: $value));
  $colours: map-merge($colours, (unquote($key+'-hover'): darken($value, 5% )) );
}

@debug $colours // (primary: blue, primary-hover: #0000e6, success: green, success-hover: #006700, warning: yellow, warning-hover: #e6e600)
```

The `variable_lookup` function remains the same.

Hope this is able to help

Comment: This is my current work-around, however, it's less-than-ideal. You can't assign modifiers to variables in a map when defining the map:

`$map = (
  btn-primary-bg: #fff,
  btn-primary-border: darken(map-get($map, "btn-primary-bg"), 5%)
)`

Comment: This is because you're making reference to the `map` inside it. It would work if you used this code `btn-primary-border: darken(#fff, 5%)`. So can I see what the variables you want to define look like

Comment: Yep, I know. But that's the point. I would have to re-iterate values that I've already previously written. Whereas with traditional variables, I can simply write my code: `$btn-primary-bg: #fff; $btn-primary-border: darken($btn-primary-bg, 5%);`

Comment: I appreciate the thought you put into this answer. While this isn't what I'm looking for, I do realize that SASS does not support variable interpolation at the moment. So for now, this is the best solution we're going to get!

Comment: Hopefully in the next release, this feature will be added. Unfortunately this is the best way to achieve this for now until the new feature is added in SASS. All the best with your project