# Scss create a variable from another variable and a string

Tags: css, string, sass, concatenation

I'm sure I'm close to my final result but for the moment, can't find out, so I ask here !

I try to make a better version of my mixin to facilitate the usage of typography in my design system, so that the user juste have to put '@include typography(body, bold, m)' and then my mixin just go to create the right string to search the right design tokens. In one line, it adds the right font-size, the right font-weight, and the line-height.

Here is my code :

```css
 $font-family-default : "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";

$body-bold-m-font-size : 34px;
$body-bold-m-font-weight: 900;
$body-bold-m-line-height: 40px;

@mixin typo($type, $weight, $size) {
  // should output a list of properties with right values.
  // actually output a list of properties with the strings(not quoted) $body-bold-m-font-size etc instead of their value.

  font-family: $font-family-default;
  color: green; // for the test
    $constructed-typo : $type+'-'+$weight+'-'+$size;
  font-size: #{'$'+$constructed-typo +'-font-size'};
  font-weight: $constructed-typo +'-font-weight';
  line-height: $constructed-typo +'-line-height';
}

.electric-sheep {
  @include typo(body, bold, m);
}
```

```
<div class="electric-sheep">Am I dreaming ? </div>
```

Can you help me to figure out that last step I miss ?

Thanks, have a nice day !

Comment: It appears this is not possible because a string value is already deemed a value, there is a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007683/15291770)

Comment: I already read this article but I'm not sure this is exactly the same case. Also it's from 2016. So I was hoping something has changed. My case can't be answered with what's recommended in this post unfortunately :)